# why this code runs out of order

Tags: java, exponentiation

This is my code and I gave inputs to it as follows, I removed the step of giving a actual output value by the user, as it is calculated in the code, but still the same thing happens

"1" for 1st input then
"0.5" for 1st inputs weight then
"0" then for the second input
"0.6" for its weight then
"0" for the desired output then
"0.002" for the defined value then
"0.23" for the learning rate.

```
 package Neural4copy;

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.lang.Math;

public class Demo {

    // inputs are declared
    private int x[][]=new int[1][2];
    //weights are declared
    private double w[][]=new double[1][2];
    private double temp;

    private double z[]=new double[1];
    private double desiredOutput;
    private double actualOutput;
    private double error;
    private double definedValue=0.004;
    private double weightChange[][]=new double[1][2];
    private double learningRate;
    private double epilision=0.000000001;
    private static double zTotal;

    private Scanner user_input= new Scanner(System.in);

    public void getData(){

        for(int j=0;j<x.length;j++){
            for(int i=0;i<x[0].length;i++){
                System.out.println("Enter "+j+"th neuron "+i+"th input values :");
                x[j][i]=user_input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter "+j+"th neuron "+i+" weight of the input value :");
                w[j][i]=user_input.nextDouble();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Enter the desired Output :");
        desiredOutput=user_input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the defined value for checking the condition");
        definedValue=user_input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter the learning rate");
        learningRate=user_input.nextDouble();

        calculate();


    }

    public void calculate(){

        for(int j=0;j<x.length;j++){
            for(int i=0; i<w[0].length; i++){
                temp=0;
                temp=x[j][i]*w[j][i];


              z[j]+=temp;

            }
            zTotal+=z[j];
            System.out.println("temp value :"+zTotal);
        }   

        System.out.println("ztotal "+zTotal);

        //double negZ= -zTotal;

        double temp2=1+Math.exp(-zTotal);
        actualOutput=1/temp2;
        //actualOutput=1/(1+Math.exp(-zTot));


        System.out.println("actualOutput "+actualOutput);

        if(Math.abs(actualOutput-desiredOutput)>epilision){

            calculateError();
        }
        else{
            printWeights();
        }






    }


    public void calculateError(){
        System.out.println("desired out put :"+desiredOutput+" actual out put :"+actualOutput);
        error=0.5*((desiredOutput-actualOutput)*(desiredOutput-actualOutput));
        System.out.println("error "+error+"\n\n");

        //error=0.003;



        checkingCondition();

    }

    public void checkingCondition(){

        if(error<definedValue){

            printWeights();
        }
        else{

            balanceWeights();
        }

    }


    public void balanceWeights(){

        //System.out.println("new Weights are");
        for(int j=0;j<w.length;j++){

            for(int i=0;i<w[0].length;i++){

                weightChange[j][i]=(-learningRate)*(desiredOutput-actualOutput)*actualOutput*(1-actualOutput)*x[j][i];
                System.out.println("weight change "+weightChange[j][i]);
                w[j][i]+=weightChange[j][i];

                //System.out.print(w[i]+"\t");
            }

        }
        calculate();




    }

    public void printWeights(){
        System.out.print("The balanced weights are: ");


        for(int j=0;j<x.length;j++){
            for(int i=0;i<x[0].length;i++){
                System.out.println("Neuron "+j+"Weight of input"+i+"=\t"+w[j][i]);
            }

        }


    }



}
```

but this codes runs out of order, with out printing out the `zTotal` first as coded in the `calculate()` method. And output start from `zTotal` as 335851.72992330056 value which is not possible,and `error` doesnot change it keep the value as 0.5 and finall "StackOverFlowError" occurs. 
why is this

This is the top part of my output

```
weight change 0.0
zTotal :348355.7408125164
temp value :348986.9403243046
ztotal 348986.9403243046
actualOutput 1.0
desired out put :0.0 actual out put :1.0
error 0.5


weight change 0.0
weight change 0.0
zTotal :348986.9403243046
temp value :349618.7111663145
ztotal 349618.7111663145
actualOutput 1.0
desired out put :0.0 actual out put :1.0
error 0.5


weight change 0.0
weight change 0.0
zTotal :349618.7111663145
temp value :350251.053338546
ztotal 350251.053338546
actualOutput 1.0
desired out put :0.0 actual out put :1.0
error 0.5


weight change 0.0
weight change 0.0
zTotal :350251.053338546
temp value :350883.96684099914
ztotal 350883.96684099914
actualOutput 1.0
desired out put :0.0 actual out put :1.0
error 0.5
```

`zTotal :348355.7408125164` why is this starts at a high value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see these values you're getting but they're not at the beginning of the output, they're further down. See: http://ideone.com/06KyMj

At the top of the output, I see:

```
temp value :0.5
ztotal 0.5
actualOutput 0.6224593312018546
desired out put :0.0 actual out put :0.6224593312018546
error 0.19372780950013005
```

This could be down to the way the output is displayed. Some environments will only show the last few thousand lines and the top will get cut off.

Answer (score -1):

Look your exception message you'll see the stack (you call method that call method )... the basic stackoverflow exception.

**calculate** > calculateError > checkingCondition > balanceWeights > **calculate**

The stack have a limited size, so you use iterative implementation but I think that this code doesn't converge when neuron value is 0 or never, I don't really understand this algorithm without comments.

Comment: Please punctuate and capitalise this mess.